# retrieveing data from multiple tables using one table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a web application for MySQL database which contains 100 tables. I want that table names in dropdown list and next on search box for searching that particular table selected in dropdown on submit .

one table contains the all table names.![enter image description here][1]

first table contains id up to 100 .I just mentioned only two other tables. Except table_names table

**Table_names**

```
id  species                 Unipept_table

1   Arabidopsis lyrata       pept_al
2   Glycine max              pept_gm
```

**pept_al**

```
species                 Proteinname                 Pept_seq

Arabidopsis lyrata         adl                  AAAAAAGTFFRQPDR
Arabidopsis lyrata         adl                  AAAAAVEAK
Arabidopsis lyrata         adl                  AAAAAEVK
```

**unipept_gma**

```
species                     Proteinname                Pept_seq

Glycine max                  Gly                      AAAAAAAAVA
Glycine max                  Gly                      AAAAAAAAVPE
Glycine max                  Gly                      AAAAAKK
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question ? its really hard to understand what you meant in the last line

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema='SCHEMA NAME'
```

or you can insert all the tables into a table & query that table to get the result. I think this should be faster.